# How to make a std::map of data type to function pointer

Tags: c++

I have a data structure like this

```
enum DataType_t{INT,FLOAT};
struct Data
{
   DataType_T type;
   void* min;
   void* max;
};
```

The variables `min` and `max` depend on the value of `type`. I want to know if there is a way to create a `std::map` like

```
std::map<DataType_t, SomeFcnPtr> myMap;
myMap[INT] = ?? // Here should be a pointer to a function like int(*FcnPtr)(Data d, bool min);
myMap[FLOAT] = ?? // Here should be a pointer to a function like float(*FcnPtr)(Data d, bool min);
```

Is there a way to create such a map that have function pointers with different return data types?

In the end I want to use it to normalize values

```
float normalizedValue = (readValue - mayMap[INT](intData, true)) / (mayMap[INT](intData, false) - mayMap[INT](intData, true))
```

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842363/c-stdmap-of-heterogeneous-function-pointers) that looks really similar but didn't understand the proposed ideas, maybe you could give an example.

**EDIT**

I will add a little bit more explanation on what I am attempting. `struct Data` has a field `DataType_t type`. Depending on the value of `type` I need to properly cast the `min` and `max` fields to have their proper representations as `int` or `float`. One possible way could be

```
int getMinOrMaxForINT(Data aData, bool min)
{
   if(min) return *((int*)aData.min));
   return *((int*)aData.max));
}
```

and similarly

```
float getMinOrMaxForFLOAT(Data aData, bool min)
{
   if(min) return *((float*)aData.min));
   return *((float*)aData.max));
}
```

finally in some function processing `Data` variables I could do

```
void someFunction(int value, Data aData)
{
   float normalizedValue = 0;
   if(aData.type == DataType_t::INT)
   {
      normalizedValue = (value - getMinOrMaxForINT(aData, true)) / (getMinOrMaxForINT(aData, false) - getMinOrMaxForINT(aData, true));
   }
   else if(aData.type == DataType_t::FLOAT)
   {
      normalizedValue = (value - getMinOrMaxForFLOAT(aData, true)) / (getMinOrMaxForFLOAT(aData, false) - getMinOrMaxForFLOAT(aData, true));
   }
}
```

as you notice the code is exactly the same for the `getMinOrMaxForXXXX` except for the return and cast types. I thought of using a template like

```
template <typename T>
T getMinOrMax(Data aData, bool min)
{
       if(min) return *((T*)aData.min));
       return *((T*)aData.max));
}
```

but the problem is how to have the map to get a pointer to a certain specialization, for example

```
myMap[DataType_t::INT] = //PointerTo getMinOrMax<int>
myMap[DataType_t::FLOAT] = //PointerTo getMinOrMax<float>
```

this could help me simplifying the function code in the process function

```
void someFunction(int value, Data aData)
{
   float normalizedValue = (value - myMap[aData.type](aData, true)) / (myMap[aData.type](aData, false) - myMap[aData.type](aData, true));
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42 could you give me an example? I don't see how boost::variant can help.

Comment: Your sample code is not consistent. If myMap values are function pointers, why have they getMin, getMax methods?

Comment: Sorry @simon, edited my question to reflect myMap values are pointers to functions. I think it is consistent now, any idea on how to construct such a map?

Comment: well, since INT is of DataType_t I assume it could be used as myMap[SomeVariable] where someVariable is of DataType_t.

Comment: @BRabbit27: but do you now the return type in that line compile time?

Comment: @simon what do you mean?, the function will have as return value whatever the return value is in the function pointer.

Comment: Is this something you want? https://ideone.com/cgcxiG *edit* Otherwise it would be possible to do with templates and lambdas.

Comment: @Appleshell Nope, I'm afraid not. I edited my question to explain in depth (I believe) my problem and attempt.

Comment: the templated function solves your problem and looks simpler, why are you making it more complicated using a map in the middle? also, why not two templated functions? getMin and getMax?

Comment: Because I want to avoid the if-else if structure, imagine I have 100 different DataType_t, coding such an if-else if-else if- ... -else if structure is not maintainable, is it?

Comment: how about create a function which gets the type needed, min or max and the callback function ? then you pass the callback function and forget anout this issue completly. you have one function that take care for int x float x min x max

Comment: @DavidHaim could you give a more detailed answer? Otherwise, I think the problem remains on how to relate `type` and `callbackFunction`.

Comment: what about a base class `Data` and derived classes `DataInt`, `DataFloat`, etc that implement the normalization function? Then you rely on polymorphism to calculate the `normalizedValue`. That will avoid the nasted if-else-if-else code, you just have to maintain the derived classes declarations (you can use some templates to make this easy). Just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::tuple< std::pair< DataType, std::function< void() >  > > myMap;`

Then implement get by type see example with a factory using this technique here:
https://github.com/alekstheod/tnnlib/blob/master/src/Utilities/Utilities/Design/Factory.h

for get by type look here:
https://github.com/alekstheod/tnnlib/blob/master/src/Utilities/Utilities/MPL/Tuple.h

Starting from here:

```
    int retInt(){
  return 1;
}

float retFloat(){
  return 1.f;
}

char retChar(){
  return 'a';
}

int main(int, char *[])
{

  std::tuple< std::pair< int, std::function< int () > >,
             std::pair< float, std::function< float() > >,
             std::pair< char, std::function< char () > > > map;

  std::get<0>(map).second = retInt;
  int result = std::get<0>(map).second();
  return 0;
}
```

This is a simple example when I take a first element from a tuple and execute the function. Now instead of getting the first element we need to find an element by using a type. A bit of metaprogramming:

```
namespace detail{

template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Args>
struct get
{
  static const auto value = N;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N, class... Args>
struct get<T, N, T, Args...>
{
  static const auto value = N;
};

template <class T, std::size_t N, class U, class... Args>
struct get<T, N, U, Args...>
{
  static const auto value = get<T, N + 1, Args...>::value;
};

}

template <class T, class... Args>
std::pair< T, std::function< T() > >& get(std::tuple<Args...>& t)
{
    using Entry = std::pair<T, std::function<T()> >;
    return std::get<detail::get<Entry, 0, Args...>::value>(t);
}
```

Then call to it will look like:

```
int main(int, char *[])
{

  std::tuple< std::pair< int, std::function< int () > >,
             std::pair< float, std::function< float() > >,
             std::pair< char, std::function< char () > > > map;

  get< int >(map).second = retInt;
  int result = get<int>(map).second();

  get< float >(map).second = retFloat;
  float result2 = get< float >(map).second();

  return 0;
}
```

You can replace a return type of the function or the function itself. Or you can keep it as it is and do a bind in case some more arguments are needed.

Comment: I wansn't able to catch the idea you proposed, I'm not very used to templates. Could you give me an example?

Comment: I added an example for you. Not really based on your code but you can adapt it very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template class instead:

```
template <typename T>
struct Data
{
   T* min; // Do you really need pointer here ?
   T* max;
};
```

So your functions become:

```
// I would prefer split the function getMin(const Data<T>& aData)
// and getMax(const Data<T>& aData) or simply directly use (*aData.min)
template <typename T>
T getMinOrMax(const Data<T>& aData, bool min)
{
    return min ? *aData.min : *aData.max;
}
```

And

```
template <typename T>
float ComputeNormalizedValue(T value, const Data<T>& aData)
{
    return float(value - *aData.min) / (*aData.max - *aData.min);
}
```

If you really need to keep your struct as

```
enum DataType_t{INT,FLOAT};
struct Data
{
   DataType_T type;
   void* min;
   void* max;
};
```

then you have to make your check at runtime in your template methods:

```
template <typename T> bool isCorrectType(const Data& aData);
template <> bool isCorrectType<int>(const Data& aData) { return aData.type = INT;}
template <> bool isCorrectType<float>(const Data& aData) { return aData.type = FLOAT;}

template <typename T>
T getMin(Data aData, bool min)
{
    if (!isCorrectType<T>(aData)) { throw std::runtime_error("Bad type"); }
    return *((T*)aData.min));
}

template <typename T>
T getMax(Data aData, bool min)
{
    if (!isCorrectType<T>(aData)) { throw std::runtime_error("Bad type"); }
    return *((T*)aData.max));
}

template <typename T>
float ComputeNormalizedValue_impl(int value, const Data& aData)
{
    return float(value - getMin<T>(aData)) / (getMax<T>(aData) - getMin<T>(aData));

}

float ComputeNormalizedValue(int value, const Data& aData)
{
    switch (aData.type)
    {
        case INT: return ComputeNormalizedValue_impl<int>(value, aData);
        case FLOAT: return ComputeNormalizedValue_impl<float>(value, aData);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use the template approach as proposed, how can I create an `std::vector` of `Data` that would allow me to use different types of Data? Say, `std::vector<Data<?>> data; data.push_back(/*Data<int>*/); data.push_back(/*Data<float>*/);`?

Comment: @BRabbit27: You cannot as this, you may create a base class, but then you have again to cast to the correct type if you don't provide virtual methods. (and store (smart) pointers).